# Moqui : in rest services how to iterate and get single column from the entity and that has to pass to next entity

Tags: moqui

I've implemented an application using Moqui Framework.if rest is like this

```
<resource name="userstores">
    <id name="parentId">
        <method type="get"><entity name="UserRoleMaps" operation="list"/></method>

         <resource name="child_Id">
            <method type="get"><entity name="users" operation="one"/></method>
         </resource>

    </id>  
</resource>
```

I have **child_Id** column in **UserRoleMaps** 
 entity, I need to get **child_Id** from **UserRolemaps** and I need to pass to **users** entity as condition to fetch data. How can I iterate it.

The url i am trying is:http://localhost:8080/moqui/rest/s1/moqui/userstores/100

Comment: This question is unclear. Are you looking for code example to do an entity find (query) and iterate over the results? Also the URL you included does not use the child_Id resource. Also by your comments perhaps child_Id should be an id and not a resource? It is all very unclear.

Answer (score 0):

I have maintained relationship in entity like this

```
<entity entity-name="UserRoleMap" package-name="moqui.security" short-alias="UserRoleMaps" allow-user-field="false" allow-remote="true">
    <field name="gropMapId" type="id-long" is-pk="true" />
    <field name="persontId" type="text-medium" />
    <field name="child_Id" type="text-medium" />

    // the below relationship parentId mean userId so it maps the childId and get the respective data related to parentId.
    <relationship type="one" title="UserType" related-entity-name="moqui.security.UserAccount" short-alias="childUserDetails">
        <key-map field-name="child_Id" related-field-name="userId"/>
    </relationship>

    <master>
        <detail relationship="childUserDetails"/>
    </master>
</entity>
```

In this way I have achieved my functionality.